# Publishing 3D scene from ArcGIS Pro 1.2 - Extruded Polygons are not working

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, 3d-map, web-scene

I am trying to publish this map to ArcGIS Online:

[image: Layer in ArcGIS Pro 1.2]

These polygons are symbolized by color based on a categorical variable and extruded based on a numerical variable.

When I publish this layer it is treated as 2D:

[image: WebScene on AGOL]

I have adjusted elevation of the layer to "relative to the ground" and 43,000 m.

Any ideas why these polygons are not extruding properly in the web scene?

Comment: It could be many things like is your Z field a string type perhaps?  Can we see your attribute data for the shapefile. Without more information it may be difficult to pinpoint your problem.

Comment: Are all the contents of the scene, such as elevation sources of the ground, basemap layer, and other layers, are in the same projected coordinate system?

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of your contents pane, where the 2D and 3D layers would normally show up in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 1):

Extruded polygons are not supported in Web Scenes at the current release.

Here's the documentation: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/map-authoring/author-a-web-scene.htm (in particular, reference the table titled "polygons").

You can work around this limitation by using the "Layer 3d to Feature Class" GP tool to create a multipatch of the extruded polygons, then publishing that multipatch to a local or hybrid Portal - however you won't be able to publish it direct to ArcGIS Online as of this release.